# C# - code refactoring to extend functionality

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have some code which calculates the tax rates for one region, Region A.

```
public class TaxCaculator
{
    public Dictionary<RegionATaxRate, decimal> CalculateTax(List<SalesDocket> sales)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<TaxRate, decimal>();
        // pseudo-code logic to calculate Region A tax rate
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `CalculateTax()` method processes a list of `SalesDocket`s which contain an `Amount` and
a `RegionATaxRate`, and returns a dictionary containing the totals against the individual `RegionATaxRate`s.

For some context, the `TaxCalculator` class will be used as follows:

```
var calculator = new TaxCalculator();
var result = calculator.CalculateTax(sales);
return result;
```

I want to extend this code so that it can be used for multiple regions - Region B, Region C, Region D, etc. However, each region will have a different tax rate. How can I modify my code to allow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `RegionATaxRate` to `RegionTaxRate` and include a property in the `RegionTaxRate` that indicates the pertinent region.

For example:

```
public class RegionTaxRate {
    public string Region {get;set;}
    public decimal TaxRate {get;set;}
}
```